# Running Analytics Against a Postgres Follower (database mirror) using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Heroku's documentation on Postgres Followers touts that "Followers may be used to ... provide a read-only view of your data for analytics", but it doesn't give any insight into how to implement this.

My plan is to have the "main database" mirrored by the "analytics db"; do some major, number-crunching sql-queries running on the analytics db, and store the results in a table in the main database.

I have not found details on how to hit the analytics database for these queries, while still using the main database for general access.  Most of the resources I've found talk about calling

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection :analytics   # and configure analytics within config/database.yml
end
```

However that will cause all storage of MyModel to be on the follower (which incidentally won't work because the follower is read-only).  I want the principle storage space to be on the main db, but just do some (read-only) access against the follower.

## Possible Solutions:

1) Have a *separate* instance of the rails app running a different environment, e.g. 'analytics' instead of 'production'.   It will therefore use the analytics db for all access.   Then store the results in

```
class AnalyticsData < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection :production if Rails.env == 'analytics'
end
```

This will cause the AnalyticsData results to be stored in the main, production db.

2) Have a *single* instance of the rails app.

- Before beginning the analytics work, call ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:analytics)
- do the crunching
- call ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:production)
- instantiate the AnalyticsData object to save the results

I'm not at all sure that latter approach will work, but it has the advantage of not having to worry about keeping the two Heroku apps in sync.

Thoughts?   Thanks!

#### References:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/improving-heroku-postgres-availability-with-followers
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-documentation#follow-beta

Answer (score 3):

The database URL of the follower will be available as a config var on your app. You can see this via `heroku config --app your-app`.

I would assign this as the READONLY_DATABASE_URL via

```
heroku config:add READONLY_DATABASE_URL=<the url> --app your-app
```

and then use any of the sharding plugins for activerecord, setting up the correct database connection params based on `ENV['READONLY_DATABASE_URL']`. I haven't used any of these, but you should investigate your options here: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Sharding (and do share what worked for you to the internet at large!)

Answer (score 1):

To access the read-only follower only for analytics work, create a separate model and either:

1. Manually point it to the proper table
2. Have the new model extend the original (giving you access to the same scopes or methods)

#### Example:

```
class AnalyzeMyModel < MyModel
  set_table_name 'my_models'

  # ...connect to follower db...

  def self.sold_today_by_model_number(model)
    NumberCrunch.create name: "#{model} sold #{Date.today}",
                        data: created_today.where(model_number: model).to_json
  end

  def self.number_sold_today_by_model_number(model)
    NumberCrunch.create name: "Number of #{model} sold #{Date.today}",
                        data: sold_today_by_model_number(model).count
  end
end

# Usage:

  numbers_crunched = AnalyzeMyModel.number_sold_today_by_model_number(9001)
  puts "#{numbers_crunched.name}: #{numbers_crunched.data}"
  # "Number of 9001 sold DATE: 9876"
```

Now, from the same app you can use MyModel as you normally would and use AnalyzeMyModel for reporting/analytics data coming from your follower.